# temporarily add commands in shell script

Tags: python, linux, shell, command

I am working on a shell script that is calling a python program (several times) which itself is calling an other program with the following line:

```
Popen("aprogram argument")
```

`aprogram` is a program that is not available on my computer and if available does trigger a mainframe process that can take some time. therefore i want a mock up.

Is it possible to create an alias that links to `amockupscript.sh` that is only accessible from inside my script and programs started from my script, but will not stay inside the system and or screw up existing installations of `aprogram`

In the end the program flow should be something like that:

I run my script. The script does some magic. The script calls `python myPythonProgram.py`. `myPythonProgram`calls `Popen("aprogram")`. Behind the curtain actually `mymockupscript.sh` is executed. After my script is finished everything is back to normal, and a regular execution of `myPythonProgram` results in its `Popen("aprogram")` calls to actually attempt to open `aprogram`

Comment: You want a solution to put in the script or something to put in the environment so that you don't have to modify the script? If you do want to modify the script, which script the shell driver or the python script?

Comment: I want a solution in the script.
The idea is: I call the script. The script does some magic step. The script calls my python program. My python program calls popen("aprogram") but actually mymockupscript.sh is called.
I am going to update the question to add my clarification.

Comment: If `aprogram` is not called by absolute or relative path but searched in environment defined path you can just put your mock in a directory and puts this directory path at the top of environment path.

Comment: Indeed. As @Micheled'Amico said if `aprogram` is called by bare name then simply create yourself a directory with your mock `aprogram` in it and place that directory at the start of the `PATH`.